# grep first occurance of a string n lines prior, once matched with another string

Tags: linux, grep

I need to find first occurance of "A" that comes n lines prior, after matching of another string "B".

Say

A(capture since nearest to next B)
..
..
B
..
..
A (Dont capture)
A (capture, nearest to next B)
..
..
B
task: capture "A"s which occur prior to "B".
Cant use grep -r -B 5 (or 6 or 7 since it could be any lines prior) "B" | grep "A"
since "A" could be any number of lines prior, and I need first occurance of such prior "A".
Basically find "A" of each "B".
Any solution?

If not grep, what would be the script to this?

Comment: Tried reverse search instead of forward search (In python) and it works!  
Pseudo code:  
>---for logline in reversed(list(open(sys.argv[1]))):
>--->---logline = logline.rstrip('\n')
>--->---if "B: " in logline:
>--->--->---flag == 1
>--->---if "A" in logline and flag == 1:
>--->--->---Address.append(logline+"\n")
>--->--->---flag == 0

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you may do this:

```
awk '/^A/ {f=$0} /^B/ {print f}' file
A(capture since nearest to next B)
A (capture, nearest to next B)
```

It stores the line in variable `f` when line starts with `A`
Later when it finds `B`